# Disallowing proxies from POSTing

Tags: apache-2.2, php, proxy, spam, blacklist

I want to disallow proxies and spambots from posting in my website. What is the best way to do so?

I've downloaded a blacklist and my first idea was to disable each of ips in my .htaccess file, but after downloading [the list](http://cbl.abuseat.org/), I found out that it contained almost 9 million entries.

My other idea was to split each IP in 4 parts and do [1;4] successive SQL queries in my POST.

Yet if I could cache this values on memory, I could inexpensively check for them with something like (:200 (:188 (:10 (:42)))). Is this doable with PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) such as [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net/)? They seem to be the industry standard for avoiding non-humans to post and would be much simpler to implement than an IP filter of 9 million blacklisted IPs.

Comment: This approach could work against a spambot, but it wouldn't disallow regular users from using proxies